# Primefaces Dataexport prints <br> tags

Tags: primefaces, data-export

I am exporting data from a p:dataTable into an excel file, and i the data in one of the columns in formatted in a special way using < br > tags.

Here is the layout:
[image: description]

The problem is when i export the table, the < br > tags are printed into the excel document like this:

[image: Excel description]

The code i am using right now:

```
                <p:column sortBy="#{serviceLevel.titleAndDescription}">
                    <f:facet name="header">Description: </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText style="font-weight:bold" value="Title: &lt;br /&gt;" escape = "false"/>
                    <h:outputText value="#{serviceLevel.title} &lt;br /&gt; &lt;br /&gt;" escape = "false"/>
                    <h:outputText style="font-weight:bold" value="Description: &lt;br /&gt;" escape = "false"/>
                    <h:outputText value="#{serviceLevel.description}" />
                </p:column>
```

I have tried to use normal < br > tags between the outputText's which gave the same effect.

I have tried to use a < p:spacer > but the exporter doesn't support it :(

Any idea's on how i can keep the layout for the user, but not show the html tags in the exported excel document?

I am using Primefaces 3.5.

Comment: Hm, never ran in such an issue but have you tried to use the pre/postProcessor as mentioned in the PF doc [here](http://primefaces.org/documentation.html) on page 119? Cheers!

Comment: I am already using a postProcessor to style the Excel sheet (the bold font and background color in the header), but i don't know if there is something i can add to the postProcessor, that would make the < br > tags disappear?

Comment: Hm, as said earlier: I've never done this by myself so I'm just suggestioning. Aren't you able to access the text inside the pre/postProcessor? If so, you could do a regex replace (all br-tags to CRLF). But the better solution would be to omit the <br> inside the table and style it via CSS eg. `<h:outputText style="font-weight:bold; padding-bottom: 20px;" value="Title:"`. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to SimonSez suggestion i managed to solve this issue with the help of some css.

Here is the solution i used:

```
            <p:column sortBy="#{serviceLevel.titleAndDescription}">
                    <f:facet name="header">Description: </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText style="font-weight:bold; display: block;" value="Title: " />
                    <h:outputText style="display: block;" value="#{serviceLevel.title}" />
                    <h:outputText style="font-weight:bold; display: block; padding-top: 20px;" value="Description: " />
                    <h:outputText value="#{serviceLevel.description}" />
                </p:column>
```